# jQuery remove ALL class on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have several buttons. When clicked I would like to remove all classes from my text field.
Currently this is what I have, but the code is not optimized.

```
var maintextarea = $('.myTextArea');
$('#styleBtn1').click(function(){
    maintextarea.removeClass('fromStyleBtn2 fromStyleBtn3');
    maintextarea.addClass('fromStyleBtn1');
    return false;
});
$('#styleBtn2').click(function(){
    maintextarea.removeClass('fromStyleBtn1 fromStyleBtn3');
    maintextarea.addClass('fromStyleBtn2');
    return false;
});
$('#styleBtn3').click(function(){
    maintextarea.removeClass('fromStyleBtn1 fromStyleBtn2');
    maintextarea.addClass('fromStyleBtn3');
    return false;
});
```

**Question**: How can I rewrite the `removeClass` portion so that when a button is clicked all previous classes will be nulled and my class gets added?

Comment: It shouldn't be [complicated](http://jsfiddle.net/NuGdM/).

Comment: Also note, your `class`ing and `id`'s seem off. `id`'s should be used for individual (specific, atomic, literal) assignments, and `class`es should be used for elements which belong to the same "group". The repetitive nature of your cited code makes me wonder if you're taking this direction to heart.

Comment: i thought i was following this pattern.  the id's are unique and class is general.  thank you for the fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply using the method chaining

```
maintextarea.removeClass().addClass('fromStyleBtn1');
```

calling removeClass() without any parameter will remove all classes.

**EDIT** : Your entire code can be replaced like this generic form.. Assuming your class name will always in the  format "from"+elementID. (Ex : fromStyleBtn2)

```
var maintextarea = $('.myTextArea'); 
$('.fromStyleBtn1,.fromStyleBtn2,.fromStyleBtn3').click(function(){
    var item=$(this);
    var newClassName="from"+item.attr("id");
    maintextarea.removeClass().addClass(newClassName);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @jimmym715 : It should be `from`, not `form` . that is from the question. I should have used format instead of form. That is y this confusion came. Will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, directly from the [jQuery documentation for .removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/):

> To replace all existing classes with another class, we can use
>   `.attr('class', 'newClass')`

Comment: i always thought attribute was for id's

Comment: nope, .attr() is for whatever attribute you need to get or set (http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to remove the class attribute instead of some of the attribute's values use [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Answer (score 1):

You can override the functionallity of removeClass like this:

```
$(function() {
    var originalRemoveClass=$.fn.removeClass;

    $.fn.extend({
        removeClass:function(toRemove, toAdd) {
            originalRemoveClass.call(this, toRemove);
            this.addClass(toAdd);            
        }
    });
});
```

you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NuGdM/1/
Another option is to create your plugin that do that (if you need an example - ask me).
Good Luck!